# RODBC read table from Access with non-standard name

Tags: r, ms-access, locale, rodbc, persian

I am working in R on a dataset provided in MS Access. As I try hard to make my code reproducible, I want to avoid doing anything to data using Access.

the database has some tables that have non-ascii characters (Persian names)

I connect to the database:

```
cns <- odbcConnectAccess2007(mdbfilename)
```

when I get a list of tables with:

```
tbls <- sqlTables(cns)
head(tbls ,10)
```

I get something like this:

```
                   TABLE_CAT TABLE_SCHEM                 TABLE_NAME   TABLE_TYPE REMARKS
1  D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA>          MSysAccessObjects SYSTEM TABLE    <NA>
2  D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA>                   MSysACEs SYSTEM TABLE    <NA>
3  D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA> MSysNavPaneGroupCategories SYSTEM TABLE    <NA>
4  D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA>          MSysNavPaneGroups SYSTEM TABLE    <NA>
5  D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA>  MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects SYSTEM TABLE    <NA>
6  D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA>       MSysNavPaneObjectIDs SYSTEM TABLE    <NA>
7  D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA>                MSysObjects SYSTEM TABLE    <NA>
8  D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA>                MSysQueries SYSTEM TABLE    <NA>
9  D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA>          MSysRelationships SYSTEM TABLE    <NA>
10 D:\\HEIS\\DataRAW\\80.mdb        <NA>    R80P1 روستا?? 80 بخش ?ک        TABLE    <NA>
```

As you can see the name of the table in row 10 contains non-standard characters.
The name of the table as shown in MS-Access is `R80P1 روستایی 80 بخش یک`. Because MS-Access tries to send the name in system's locale (which is Persian) it converts the data to Windows-Arabic encoding (codepage 1256) which does not contain a code for Persian Yeh (`ی`) (which is different than Arabic Yeh (`ي`)).

It makes it impossible to read the data in this table from R, as we really do not have the name:

```
tbl <- tbls[10,3]
RD <- sqlQuery(cns,paste0("Select Address from ",tbl))
head(RD)
```

I get this error:

```
[1] "07002 17 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect "            
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'Select Address from R80P1 روستا?? 80 بخش ?ک'"
```

I have tried to solve this problem in various ways

1. Rename tables in MS-Access, as my script is going to download 30+ files from internet, extract them and read them, this does not seem viable to do this manual renaming for one of the files (that has this weird naming) in the middle of process.
2. Change the encoding when opening connection, I've tried this with all 374 encodings available from `iconvlist()`, does not solve the problem. An important case: opening ODBC connection using `UTF-8`, causes the problematic table names to be returned as `NA`.
3. Try to read the table not by name but by index in database, but I don't know how to do that using RODBC (I know the index by `grepl`ing the initial part of name in Latin)
4. Try to use `sqlFetch()` with a custom SQL query that uses regular expression on table name, I don't know how to do this or even if this is possible.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
I have to add my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Persian_Iran.1256  LC_CTYPE=Persian_Iran.1256    LC_MONETARY=Persian_Iran.1256
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=Persian_Iran.1256    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.6 foreign_0.8-65   RODBC_1.3-12     yaml_2.1.13     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2  chron_2.3-47
```

P.S. For those interested in struggling with the actual problem, the file I'm talking about is available for download from: http://www.amar.org.ir/Portals/0/amarmozuii/hazinedaramad/80.rar
 (~18 MB)

Comment: There are spaces in your table name. Try enclosing with brackets `[]`. Also, R does show the correct Persian Yeh character in list of tables and even in error message.

Comment: As @Parfait suggests, `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM [R80P1 روستایی 80 بخش یک]` works for me (in C# using `System.Data.Odbc`, anyway).

Comment: @parfait and @gord-thompson, I tried enclosing table name in brackets [], but that did not work, and as you can see in the question, R does not show the correct Persian Yeh character in list of tables for me. I know this is not R's fault, or even MS-Access, as they each do fine with Persian. Maybe your locale is different and that helps. whould you please add your `Sys.locale()` results here?

Comment: As best practices, it is recommended to keep names of databases, tables, and columns expressive but concise for maintainability in query scripting. As you seem to use English column names (`address`), consider keeping all in one language type that is platform-agnostic.

Comment: The problem is that these are data provided by external sources, I just write scripts to work on these data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is not R's fault, or even MS-Access, as they each do fine with Persian.

It seems to be a limitation of RODBC, which does appear to rely on the Windows locale for interpreting the character encoding of table names. When I try

```r
> tbls <- sqlTables(cns)
> head(tbls, 10)
```

I get

```
                    TABLE_CAT TABLE_SCHEM                 TABLE_NAME
1  C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA>          MSysAccessObjects
2  C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA>                   MSysACEs
3  C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA> MSysNavPaneGroupCategories
4  C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA>          MSysNavPaneGroups
5  C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA>  MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects
6  C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA>       MSysNavPaneObjectIDs
7  C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA>                MSysObjects
8  C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA>                MSysQueries
9  C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA>          MSysRelationships
10 C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80.MDB        <NA>    R80P1 ??????? 80 ??? ??
```

because my Windows locale, English (United States), does not recognize *any* of the Persian/Arabic characters. Furthermore, I am unable to query the table even if I specify its name directly

```r
> RD <- sqlQuery(cns, 'SELECT Address FROM [R80P1 روستایی 80 بخش یک]')
> head(RD)
[1] "42S02 -1305 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'R80P1 <U+0631><U+0648><U+0633><U+062A><U+0627><U+06CC><U+06CC> 80 <U+0628><U+062E><U+0634> <U+06CC><U+06A9>'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly."
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT Address FROM [R80P1 <U+0631><U+0648><U+0633><U+062A><U+0627><U+06CC><U+06CC> 80 <U+0628><U+062E><U+0634> <U+06CC><U+06A9>]'"
```

If you don't want to rename the tables in the source database then you might consider the following workaround:

- Create a new Access database named "80links.accdb".
- Use `External Data > Import & Link > Access` to create a *linked* table that points to the [R80P1 روستایی 80 بخش یک] table in the source database ("80.MDB").
- Rename the linked table to use an English name with no spaces, e.g., [Section_80_rural_R80P1]
- Run your queries against the linked table.

```r
> mdbfilename <- 'C:\\__tmp\\zzzTest\\80links.accdb'
> cns <- odbcConnectAccess2007(mdbfilename)
> RD <- sqlQuery(cns, 'Select Address from Section_80_rural_R80P1')
> head(RD)
  Address
1   11001
2   11001
3   11001
4   11001
5   11001
6   11001
```